# wget and scp as a pipeline

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, wget, scp

Can we use wget and scp as a pipeline. I want to wget a file from a server and copy to another server. I used below command but it is not working.

```
wget "$Select_Release_Version_ARTIFACT_URL" | sudo scp test@192.168.94.137:/etc/test/
```

Answer (score 3):

To use `wget` in a pipe, you must make sure it writes to `stdout` instead to a file, so use `wget -O- ...`.

AFAIK, you can't use `scp` to copy from `stdin`. However, you can use `ssh` instead, and have it execute a command like `cat`, which reads from `stdin`.

So together you get something like

```
wget -O- "$Select_Release_Version_ARTIFACT_URL" | ssh test@192.168.94.137 'cat > /etc/test/some_file'
```

Note that will only download and transfer a single file/webpage. Also note that user `test` on `192.168.94.137` needs rights to create and write to `/etc/test/some_file`. Using `sudo` before `ssh` won't give the remote user `test` any additional rights. It will allow to access ssh keys of root on the local machine, so if that was the intention, keep it.

While this demonstrates how to use a pipe over `ssh`, it would have been easier to just execute `wget` on the remote machine, unless there are reasons why this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pipe, you can use `&&`. This will make sure that when `scp` runs if `wget` has exit status of 0 (finished successfully).

> wget "$Select_Release_Version_ARTIFACT_URL" && sudo scp "$Select_Release_Version_ARTIFACT_URL" test@192.168.94.137:/etc/test/

This works as following:

`wget` downloads the file and IF SUCCESSFUL, it will initiate `scp`.

NOTE: Since you are using `sudo`, this will ask the password `test` user every time this command will run.

Comment: I used passwordless authentication, I think no need of providing password.

Comment: When I using above command I am getting error. `wget` is working but `scp` is not working.

Comment: Note that if the named file already exists, wget will download into `filename.1`, `filename.2`, etc.

Comment: Yes can I write a scrip to download and copy to remote machine same time?